# Disabling static file serving for Next

Tags: next.js

Is there a way to disable static file serving for Next? Right now my assets are in a directory called /public. I am fine with files being served statically by Next when the app is run locally, but I want them to be served from nginx when the app is deployed into stage and production. Is there a better way to do this aside from renaming the /public directory?

Comment: I think a better way is to serve your assets from a CDN and add the CDN prefix in front of assets path.

Comment: Doesn't this part of the documentation mean I would have to edit every image URL to add the asset prefix in front? It sounds doable, just annoying.

"Asset prefix support does not influence the following paths:

Files in the public folder; if you want to serve those assets over a CDN, you'll have to introduce the prefix yourself"

Comment: As far as I know, Yes, you will need to do that for all the images if you want to use the /public folder approach. You can also use the next-images, which you can set a asset prefix globally. You will probably prefer next-images